# Product of List of Polynomials in Macaulay2

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

I am currently writing a function in Macaulay2 which given an elementary symmetric function $e_i$ outputs its expression in terms of power sums according the formula:

$$e_n=\sum_{|\lambda|=n}(-1)^{|\lambda|-l(\lambda)} z_{\lambda}^{-1}p_{\lambda}$$ where $|\lambda|$ is the size of the partition $\lambda$ and $l(\lambda)$ is its length, $p_{\lambda}=p_{\lambda_1}p_{\lambda_2}\cdots$ and 
$$z_{\lambda}=\prod_{i\geq 1}\left(i^{m_i}\cdot m_i!\right)$$
where $m_i$ is the number of parts of $\lambda$ equal to $i$.

I am close but due to my ignorance of the language I am missing two important parts of the program:

(1) A way to find all positive integer solutions to the equation $\sum_{i=1}^nix_i = m$ (i.e. the partitions of $m$ as $n$-tuples).

(2) Given a list of polynomials, a way to compute the product of all elements in that list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `R=QQ[x,y,z]` `product {x,y,z} -- x*y*z`

Comment: FWIW `R=QQ[x,y,z,Degrees=>{1,2,3}]` `basis(3,R) -- x^3, x*y, z`.

Comment: Thank you that first comment was helpful!

Comment: For the second comment, look at the multidegrees: $(3,0,0), (1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ are the "weighted" partitions of three.

Comment: So you are saying to reduce this to a problem which considers all the ways we can obtain a monomial of a specific degree by using weighted variables?

Comment: As in considering the ring $\mathbf{Q} [x_1, x_2^2, x_3^3..., x_n^n]$?

Comment: Yes, given $n$; `R=QQ[x_1 .. x_n,Degrees=>{1..n}]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96677/discussion-between-brandon-thomas-van-over-and-jan-magnus-okland).

Comment: Converting the other way may be done in the [SymmetricPolynomials](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.14/share/doc/Macaulay2/SymmetricPolynomials/html/index.html)-package. Look at the code linked in the documentation.